# HBase Configuration with Hadoop 1.0.3

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am installing **hadoop-1.0.3** in widow-7 using **cygbin**. Now i want to install **HBase** so please suggest me which version of Hbase compatible with hadoop 1.0.3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the list of compatibility matrix between Hadoop and HBase versions:

[image]

Above: S - Supported, X - Not Supported, NT - Not Tested

More Info available here: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html